# node.js express send response from variable to the browser and not the console

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am learning node.js
easy to user res.send and some hello world text
but how do I send variables?? to the browser and not the console ??

code example

```
var Tester = require ('search-google')
  , google = new search.Google();

google.list({search parameter,more,more,
})
.then(function (res) {
console.log('results from google', res);
}).catch(function(err) {
console.log('err', err);
});
```

I tried res write send create server and I still cant understand this
any help much appreciated

Comment: Could you include the express setup and route you are using in the code example? Like `app.get()`.

Comment: https://github.com/ pevers/ imagesscraper 
thats the project i am tryiing to implement but couldnt understand how to create it into a res req method with browser parmaters
i am still very new to node

Answer (score 0):

Try stringifying the variable before passing to express's send method.

`res.send(JSON.stringify(variable));`

If the variable is not a string, express sets the contenttype header as json, but you want contenttype header to be html;

Comment: thank you fro your help
i tried several things
i already used circular-json project from githuband trued stringfy it  didnt hellp much 
the problem is my understanding of how to point the response to the browser and how to send params to the function from the browseri am missing something else for sure .......